# Grails JSONObject parse issue

Tags: javascript, json, grails, groovy

hrere is an example for the issue:

the command:

```
(new JSONObject([a:[b:1]])).toString()
```

will result:

```
{"a":"{b=1}"}
```

when I was expecting to get

```
{"a":{"b":1}}
```

what am I missing?

Comment: found the solution, I was using the wrong approach:(new JSON([a:[b:1]]).toString())

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this in a controller, you can convert using the grails JSON converter:

```
import grails.converters.JSON
...
render [a:[b:1]] as JSON
```